# Why I don't receive broadcast message Laravel Pusher?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

**My event broadcast looks as:**

```
class OrderStatusUpdate implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $username;

    public $message;

    public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return 'my-event';
    }

    public function __construct($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->message = "Order status by {$username} was changed";
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {

        return ['my-event'];
    }
}
```

**Call event like:**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    OrderStatusUpdate::dispatch('Nick');
    return "Event has been sent!";
});
```

Client side is:

```
 var pusher = new Pusher('018814b79958ee4f2ad1d', {
      cluster: 'eu',
      forceTLS: true
    });

    var channel = pusher.subscribe('my-event');
    channel.bind('my-event', function(data) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
```

All `.env` settings are correct!

As you can see I use default Laravel settings and channel name. But message comes with error in Pusher server. But I dont get them on HTML page, with code JS showed upper.

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain from client side:

```
var channel = pusher.subscribe('order');
    channel.bind('OrderStatusUpdate', function(data) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
```

`order` id name of channel
`OrderStatusUpdate` is event name Event

It mean server should be:

```
public function broadcastAs()
{
  return 'OrderStatusUpdate'; // Event name
}

public function broadcastOn()
{

  return ['order'];
}
```

But I am not sure about this array sintax: `return ['order'];`, try instead this:

```
public function broadcastOn()
{

 return new Channel("order");
}
```